# Spring Model variable in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

How can I use the Model variable set in Spring Controller, in my Angular Controller and assign it to a scope variable.

e.g :

`public String myMethod(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){`
`model.addAttribute("blahKey", "blahValue");`

`return "myPage";`
`}`

Now, I want to use blahValue in my Angular controller and assign it to a scope variable.

eg. `$scope.angularBlah = doSomethingToGet("blahKey");`

Is it possible to do in some way?

The crudest approach was to use a scriptlet to assign JS variables using ${blahKey} in document.ready(), and then re-using them in angular controller.

Answer (score 0):

Spring and Angular run in different processes, on different machines (outside of dev).

Spring runs java on the server. Angular runs JavaScript in the browser.

Which means you need to marshal data between them. In this case you would want to send JSON between the client and server.

You can pass a model to a JSP view , as a JSP is processed on the server, and returns only HTML to the browser.

You could technically process a JSP page on the server and return an angular app, but that's probably not what you want.

Check out Spring Data REST , it helps you create a RESTful API from repositories.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. My JSP has the value, which I need to pass to my JS. I am using getElementById, which I think is a dirty way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

**How I got around the problem:**

The crudest approach was to use a scriptlet to assign JS variables using ${blahKey} in document.ready(), and then re-using them in angular controller.